# Multipart upload list files

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

How I can upload list files from the client with ktor?

I try:

```
newPostDto.images.map {
    append("images", it)
}
```

But its variant does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example (for more information you could check out [this repo](https://github.com/halcyonmobile/MultiplatformPlayground/blob/master/common/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/halcyonmobile/multiplatformplayground/api/ApplicationApi.kt) for a complete image file upload example)

```
client.submitFormWithBinaryData(
        formData {
            appendInput(key = ICON_FILE_PART, headers = Headers.build {
                append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${appId}_ic")
            }) {
                buildPacket { writeFully(icon.toByteArray()) }
            }
        }) {
        apiUrl("$APPLICATIONS_BASE_URL/${appId}/icon")
    }
```